# Set next div's height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the height of next div using jQuery or Javascript. My HTML structure is as below:

```
<div class="swiper-slide class2" id="2" style="width: 1263px; height: 9942px;">
    <div class="content-slide test2"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried below, but it is not working

```
$("#2").next().height(result11);
```

Comment: `$("#2").find('div').height(result11);`

Comment: So next there is a div next this div?

Comment: Check this link : http://jsfiddle.net/v4agfadu/

Answer (score 3):

`next()` is used for siblings, whereas the element you appear to want to target is a child. As such you can use `find()`:

```
$("#2").find('div').height(result11);
```

Or `children()`:

```
$("#2").children().first().height(result11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$("#2 > div").height(2740px)
```

It will selects all `<div>` elements where the parent is a `<div id="2">` element.

Answer (score 0):

required div element is child of targeted element. you need to use `.find("div")` instead of using `.next()`

```
$("#2").find('div').height(result11);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the height of immediate next child `div` we can use [`:first-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).
Hence,

```
$( "#2 div:first-child" ).height(result11);
```